# Как сделать автоматическое развертывание разных копий своего сайта?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, развертывание

Здравствуйте!
Есть php сайт написанный на laravel с бд mysql.
Мне необходимо автоматическое копирование этого сайта на сервере
с новыми настройками и новой базой.
Для примера можно сказать так - автоматическое развертывание wordpress
с прописанными дополнительными настройками в бд. Но в моем случае не wordpress а свой сайт.

Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть варианты для решения такого рода задач.
На сервере установлена ispmanager панель.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup, может бекапчик потом развернуть ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете поступить несколькими способами:

1. Написать свой APS скрипт, который будет устанавливать и распаковывать так, как вам требуется. Для этого воспользуйтесь документацией по APS (http://www.apsstandard.org/)
2. Написать скрипт, который по заданному вами условию будет копировать директорию, и прописывать нужные ключи в ENV файл
3. Просто скопировать папку и воспользоваться пакетом laravelInstaller(https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller) для установки подобно обычному веб приложению.
4. Разворачивать в Докер контейнере.
5. Загружать с github или аналогичной платформы и делать composer install, предварительно прописав файле компосера дополнительные условия инсталяции